# What tool for scraping in Laravel

Tags: python, php, laravel, screen-scraping

I would like build a website needing scraping in other site, in Laravel 7. I have to fill forms and click. I saw that it's possible with python. The scraping will do itself every hours. I saw also Laravel dusk but it doesn't work in production environnement. What technologie you adviser me to use ? I don't know python so I will learn if it's more adapted.

Thanks

Comment: check scrappy framework: https://scrapy.org/

Comment: Does it require running client JS code in real browser? Screenshots? If not (just http requests, filling forms, going through pages) since its PHP consider Symfony BrowserKit https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/browser_kit.html . 
And if you need all of this take a look at https://github.com/symfony/panther

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options depending on what you want to do.

If you're working with a site that isn't an SPA, then you can simply use the included [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php) package that comes with PHP, you can use curl to get the page HTML and parse it using the PHP DOM package.

However if you want to navigate the site and go through a scenario, then you'd best use something like [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk), [Puphpteer](https://github.com/rialto-php/puphpeteer), [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).

In the past I've used [Puphpteer](https://github.com/rialto-php/puphpeteer) before and it works great, here's a sample

```
$puppeteer = new Puppeteer();
$browser = $puppeteer->launch([
    'headless' => true,
    'args' => [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
    ]
]);

$page = $browser->newPage();
$page->goto('https://facebook.com');
$page->type('#username', 'email');
$page->type('#pass', 'password');
$page->click('button.btn__primary--large.from__button--floating');
```

This script opens facebook.com in a headless browser, and fills the fields with `email` and `password` and clicks on the button with the css selector of `button.btn__primary--large.from__button--floating`

Answer (score 0):

> fill forms and click

It means you have to do trivial POST requests.
**PHP curl** is good at it:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://testing-ground.webscraping.pro/textlist');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['a' => 'abc']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$page = curl_exec($curl); 
if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
} 
curl_close($curl);
```

For more details check [here](https://webscraping.pro/scraping-in-php-with-curl/).